# Web Page Crashing Android Browsers

Tags: javascript, android, browser, crash

Can anyone help me figure out why this page causes Android browsers to crash?

http://thewellcommunity.org

All sub-pages seem to work just fine, but when I load the home page on an Android, the browser app just closes without any warning or error messages.  I've tried this on 3 Android phones and on a Kindle Fire.

When I completely disable JavaScript in the browser on the phone, the page loads successfully.  Unfortunately this is a live website, so I'd prefer to save disabling chunks of JavaScript on the server side as a last resort.

On a side note, Opera Mini, Opera Mobile and Firefox on an Android phone do not crash, but Dolphin, Miren and the stock browser do.

UPDATE: It appears that I spoke too soon when I said this was fixed. I was able to reduce how often the browser crashes, but it still does occasionally crash when the page is loaded. :(

UPDATE #2: It now appears that the crash may be CSS related. After spending weeks enabling and disabling various JavaScript snippits, I tried disabling the stylesheet, and now I can't get it to crash.

Anyone know of an Android CSS bug that might be causing this?  My guess is that it's related to some CSS that only gets accessed after the JavaScript does it's work.

Comment: Worked for me just fine on a Nexus S with ice cream sandwich.

Comment: Definitely crashes for me on a 2.2.2 Galaxy S Wi-Fi. Loads okay in the emulator under 3.2, though. Guessing you're running into a known (and now fixed) bug in older Android versions. I'll see if I can get it to crash in a 2.2 emulator; I might be able to get a stack trace that will track down *which* bug it might be...

Comment: No crash for me, Android 2.2.2, Galaxy Spica (SamdroidMod), although there are a couple of minor layout issues. It might be a Flash issue (I don't have Flash), have you tried disabling the Flash video?

Comment: Yeah, could be Flash; the phone it's crashing on for me *does* have Flash.

Comment: you can copy the homepage to `secret.html` and test/disable stuff all you want.

Comment: Chris - You're awesome! Why didn't I think of that?!  I saved the home page to a static HTML file and then started deleting javascript references one by one until I found the culprit.  Turns out there was some garbage ASP.Net JavaScript code that was causing a problem. Found a way to remove that script and everything seems to be working great now!  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to everyone else for the input.  I appreciate it!  On a side note, I'm still fairly new to how StackOverflow works... is there a way to mark Chris' comment as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the culprit... It appears that a css font-family rule was to blame. Although, I'm not sure why since the same font stack is used several other places on the site.  :\

Here's the line that caused the problem...

```
.Site-Search .Buttons input 
{
    ...
    font-family: TeXGyreHerosRegular, Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    ...
}
```

For whatever reason that line caused all stock Android browsers to crash.  Weird.

Comment: For me I had float: right; in a rule and also float: left; in the same rule that was crashing the Android browser.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Weinre](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre). An explanation can be seen in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nL6xey13fE) youtube movie.
That way you can debug the Android webkit browser just like the well known Firebug.

In Eclipse's emulator (2.3) it loads fine but has some layout flaws.

Comment: That look's pretty amazing. I'm definitely going to have to try that out sometime. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone came here looking for a possible reason why all of their mobile's different browsers crash after a several seconds when loading a particular website it may be due to the version of jQuery employed.

For example, the LG-p690f and HTC Incredible S are some of several Android 2.3.x phones known to have troubles with fade transitions in jQuery 1.8.1 and 1.8.2 due to a browser javascript bug that will cause jQuery's `Animation` function to fail at this line:

```
percent = 1 - ( remaining / animation.duration || 0 )
```

If you are the owner of the website you can try upgrading to 1.8.3 (or downgrading to 1.7.x if allowed). Otherwise, you can send an e-mail to the website.

Sources:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12497

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/1019